# Learning Agile & Scrum

Tags: web-development, agile, scrum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a canonical book on Agile?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-agile)

I'm looking for a good book on learning Agile and Scrum for web application development. Can anyone suggest a good resource that guides one from the group up?

We want to start implementing this into our business and web application development cycles.