# Using Agile development in a one person team

Tags: agile, solo-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Agile for the Solo Developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220/agile-for-the-solo-developer)

I am going to be starting a project soon and plan to use as much of agile methods as I can (CI, TDD etc.). What have been people's experiences doing agile development when working solo? I want to get good practices in place now while its a one person team so when I scale up to having several people the basics are in place.

Comment: Pair programming works if you have multiple personalities :)

Comment: The daily stand-up should be interesting...

Comment: @david - not in my experience.

Comment: Eddie you so crazy

Comment: @davidhaskins: that's correct. Very few know that Agile programming dates back to 1886, thanks to Robert Louis Stevenson. His manuscript "Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde" is considered to be the seminal work in this field.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2175735/25507

Comment: @Josh That should have been moved to Programmers...interesting it lasted so long over on SO...

Comment: Try the pomodoro technique to keep you focused on one task at a time. It's awfully hard to work alone and keep the stress levels down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A facet of Agile would be KANBAN. I would use a KANBAN board to manage your workload and have your TO DO / IN PROGRESS / DONE swimlanes out on a wall. Just put up stickies for what needs to get done.

Also +1 for TDD

Answer (score 4):

TDD is the easiest tool to use in a one person project or, as I do, in a bigger project where developers do debugging/unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

XP/TDD scales from one to one thousand. Pair programming is optional.

Comment: Pair programming with yourself could lead to funny looks as you discuss options with you partner :-)

Comment: @Martin: just make a mp3 recording of someone else saying things at random like "are you sure about that? did you cover all the edge cases? i think i see a typo? does that need another unit test? isn't it time to check in the changes so far?" and so on.

Comment: :-) I'll try that.

Comment: @Tux-D, it would be no different than rubber ducking

Comment: I could pair with my cat

Comment: @CaffGeek True, but that's a great way to Talk to the Duck. I wonder why no one's made a Furby/Duck/Whatever that spouts off comments like that whenever you vocalize a question. With speech recognition tech these days it should be a piece of cake..

Answer (score 0):

I would say try personal scrum..its an interesting way to speed up your 'any' kind of project even if only one person is envolved. may be check out http://blog.jgpruitt.com/tag/agile-methodology/