# Agile methodology for a single developer working on a prototype

Tags: agile, methodology, solo-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Agile for the Solo Developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220/agile-for-the-solo-developer)

For my thesis I will be working on a user interface prototype during a 6 month period. I am required to pick a strategy and create a precise planning. While reading through different descriptions of agile methodologies I felt like I'm in buzz-word heaven. Instead of just picking one because it's famous, I was hoping someone could give some insight into which one/or which parts of it might be useful.

Are there any agile methodologies specifically suitable (or scalable) for single developers?

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question on StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829497/agile-methods-specifically-taylored-to-working-solo.

One of the answers provides a link to the [Pomodoro](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/) technique, and there is an interesting presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/reborg/agile-pomodoro-development).